# How to dynamically sum multiple input records in a PHP while loop using java-script onfocusout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm using a way to calculate the value of this id `id="salenag<?php echo $a; ?>"` 
multiple values which come from the database using PHP and then I'll add value into the input field the sum of all multiples input fields show in id no `sale_nag`.
I'm using for this a Javascript method but it did not work;
how it works correctly  its use for point of sale to stock out. I want a solution. Please help me out.

```
<input type='text' value='0' id='sale_nag'>
  <table>
    <?php
    $a =1;
    while ($pro_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_pro)) {
      $rm =  $pro_row['room'];
      $ra =  $pro_row['rack'];
      $sal =  $pro_row['sale_nag'];
      $ma = $pro_row['marka'];
      $cha = $pro_row['chalan'];


      $pro_query2="SELECT *,SUM(sale_nag) AS snag FROM stockout_details  WHERE  marka='$ma' and chalan='$cha' and room='$rm' and rack='$ra'
      ";
      $select_pro2 = mysqli_query($con, $pro_query2);
      $pro_row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_pro2);
      if ( $sal - $pro_row2['snag'] > 0) {

        ?>
        <div class="form_grid_2 d-none"  >
          <input name="inv[]" required class=""  value="<?php echo $inv_pro1 ; ?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">inv #</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form_grid_2 d-none"  >
          <input name="purchi[]" required class=""  value="<?php echo $id ; ?> "   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Purchi #</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form_grid_2 d-none"  >
          <input name="invstockin[]" required class="" readonly value="<?php echo $pro_row['stockoutinv'];?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Inv#</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form_grid_2"  >
          <input name="marka[]" required class=""  readonly value="<?php echo $ma = $pro_row['marka'];?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Marka #</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form_grid_2 "  >
          <input name="chalan[]" required class=" " readonly value="<?php echo $cha = $pro_row['chalan'];?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Chalan #</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form_grid_2 "  >
          <?php

          ?>
          <input name="nag[]"  class="" readonly value="<?php
          echo   $sal - $pro_row2['snag'] ;
          ?>"    type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">NAG #</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form_grid_2 " >
          <input name="outnag[]"  id="salenag<?php echo $a; ?>" onfocusout="chachvalue(<?php echo $a; ?>);" class=""  value="0"    type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Nag stock-out #</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form_grid_2 "  >
          <input name="room[]" required class="" readonly value="<?php echo $pro_row['room'];?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Room #</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form_grid_2 "  >
          <input name="rack[]" required class="" readonly  value="<?php echo $pro_row['rack'];?>"   type="text"/>
          <span class="label_intro ">Rack #</span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function  chachvalue(<?php echo $a;?>){

          var x1 = document.getElementById('salenag<?php echo $a ;?>').value;
          var x2 = document.getElementById('sale_nag').value;
          var result  = x1 + x2 ;
          document.getElementById('sale_nag').value=result;

        }

        </script>


        <?php
  $a++; }  


      }
      ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is tagged `jQuery`, I'm assuming you can use it.

First, change your function to this:

```
function chachvalue(element) { 
    
    // get value of input that unfocused
    var x1 = parseInt(element.val()); 
    
    // select #sale_nag element
    var sale_nag = $('#sale_nag');

    // set value of sale_nag to sale_nag + x1
    sale_nag.val(parseInt(sale_nag.val()) + x1);

}
```

Now, create a jQuery handler for your inputs

```
$('.outnag_input').on('focusout', function() {
    chachvalue($(this));
});
```

Now your input element can be simplified to this

```
<input name="outnag[]" class="outnag_input" value="0" type="text"/>
```

You should also move the `chachvalue()` function AND the `focusout` handler to *outside* of the PHP loop.

Comment: but I need this function on ever input field and i think this is included inside  the whileloop @grumpy

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanRajpotzada It will be attached to every input field by the field class. JavaScript works way different than PHP, the function is not specific to any single input field, instead it selects it based on the class. It needs to be outside of the loop.

Comment: dear its still an error  it give this error chachvalue is not define